# Xamarin forms dynamic notification

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm building a Xamarin Cross platform app and I need to send notifications to all client devices when insert data into database. I tried Firebase but when I send notifications from fcm console it works perfectly but when I try to do it from code it doesn't works.

I tried this code when insert is done but is not working:

```
string json_noti =
Authorization:key=AAAAnu... 
Content-Type:application/json 

{\"to\":\"/topics/noti\",\"notification\":{\"body\": \"test \",\"title\": \"test text\"}}";

StringContent post = new StringContent(json_noti);

var resposta_noti = await client.PostAsync("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",post);

var resultat = resposta_noti.StatusCode;
```

Can someone help me to send this dynamic notifications? Thx.

Comment: After the inesert is done, do you want to send the messages to specific top by FCM? If so, you can use  `Message` and `FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync` to send this notification https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics

Comment: I try it but when i install the package i have this error:                             
 Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 71.1740.0 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 71.1740.0 supports: monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0) proba_noti.iOS C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\proba_noti\proba_noti.iOS\proba_noti.iOS.csproj 1

Comment: Please try to use following ways to fix this issue https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/133056/project-is-not-compatible-with-monoandroid-8-1

Comment: Okay I think I can do it but when execute the code I have this error: "InvalidRegistration". I tryed with server key and legacy key but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using firebase push notification

Comment: Provide a bit more descriptive answer, as whoever will have the same type of question in the future, will be able to solve his/her query based on answer provided by you.